# Migration generated with owned entities not generating foreign keys

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

I'm creating a new DB using EF Core with a code-first approach. For brevity, I'm supposed to make a schema that allows the following relationship:

```
Fund -> Relations -> Fund
```

Basically, a fund can be related to many funds. A fund it's not exclusively related to only another fund.

I tried to make this mapping with the following configuration:

```cs
internal sealed class FundClassConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<FundClass>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FundClass> fundClass)
    {
      // [..] 
      fundClass.OwnsMany(f => f.FundRelations, relation =>
      {
        relation.ToTable("FundoRelacionamento");

        relation.HasKey(r => r.Id);

        relation.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("FundoId");

        relation.HasOne(r => r.RelatedFund)
          .WithMany(f => f.FundRelations)
          .HasForeignKey("FundoRelacaoId")
          .IsRequired();

        relation.HasOne(r => r.Type).WithMany()
          .HasForeignKey("TipoRelacionamentoFundoId")
          .IsRequired();
      });
    }
}
```

When I run the initial migration, the model generates the following:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "FundoRelacionamento",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        TipoRelacionamentoFundoId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
        FundoRelacaoId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false),
        FundoId = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_FundoRelacionamento", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_FundoRelacionamento_Fundo_FundoRelacaoId",
            column: x => x.FundoRelacaoId,
            principalTable: "Fundo",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_FundoRelacionamento_TipoRelacionamentoFundo_TipoRelacionamentoFundoId",
            column: x => x.TipoRelacionamentoFundoId,
            principalTable: "TipoRelacionamentoFundo",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

Why is the foreign key constraint for the owner of the entity not being generated? I expected a 3rd foreign key like

```cs
...
table.ForeignKey(
  name: "FK_FundoRelacionamento_Fundo_FundoId",
  column: x => x.FundoId,
  principalTable: "Fundo",
  principalColumn: "Id",
  onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
...
```